# How to customize Tikz Gantt chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart, pgfgantt, charts

I am trying to find a way to obtain the following using tikz (actually using `pgfgantt`):

[image]

The code I have so far is:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[ hgrid, group progress label node/.append style={below=3pt} ]{1}{12} 
\ganttbar[]{Devices On}{3}{11} \\
\ganttbar[]{Lights On}{1}{12}\\
\gantttitle{Daily Working Time}{12}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

For what I obtain:

[image: Gantt Image obtained with Overleaf]

How to obtain nearly the exact result?

Comment: Do you need just what you show in the image, or will the chart be expanded with more info?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for the quick reply. Well, right now I just need it (basically) exactly the same. But I'd like a solution that allows me to expanded intuitively (you know, colors, maybe more xlabels and all that stuff).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One suggestion. The colors of the bars can be changed by modifying the `bar` style in the optional argument to `\ganttbar`. For the *Daily working time* I suggest adding it as a `label` to the `canvas` instead of as an element in the chart, that way you don't need any additional work to remove the lines and reduce the height of the box surrounding the bars.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
  hgrid,
  group progress label node/.append style={below=3pt},
  canvas/.append style={label=below:Daily working time} ]{1}{12} 
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={draw=orange!50,fill=orange!30}]{Devices On}{3}{11} \\
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={draw=blue!50,fill=blue!30}]{Lights On}{1}{12}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the sake of curiosity, what is the `border=3mm` parameter in the `document class` declaration for? Also, isn't there a way to have a transparent color as the fill (instead of mixing white with orange)?

Comment: @Hans  Oh, that just adds a border at the sides of the page, try it and you'll see. Makes it easier to take a screenshot of the output (without getting any of the grey background from the PDF viewer) that I can paste directly into the image upload dialog here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. On the other hand, based on your explanation I posted my own answer (that I will not accept because the code is just a modification of yours) in an informative manner. Feel free to check it out.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the suggestion from the accepted answer, a code that reproduces almost exactly the image above is the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\definecolor{TableOrange}{RGB}{255,151,46}
\definecolor{TableBlue}{RGB}{38,125,184}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
  hgrid,
  group progress label node/.append style={below=3pt},
  canvas/.append style={label=below:Daily working time} ]{1}{12} 
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={line width=1pt, draw=TableOrange,fill=TableOrange,fill opacity=0.6274509804}]{Devices On}{3}{11} \\
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={line width=1pt, draw=TableBlue,fill=TableBlue,fill opacity=0.6274509804}]{Lights On}{1}{12}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

## Desired Result:

[image: Image obtained from question]

## Obtained Result:

[image: Image obtained with LaTeX]